# How can I force Ubuntu to boot on a stuck boot menu?

Tags: server, boot, grub2, headless

I have Ubuntu Server 11.04, but it is headless (no monitor). The only way I want to be able to access it is remotely via SSH. But, sometimes, say after a power loss, when the server restarts, it will get stuck on the Grub boot menu, and it won't count down. It will just hang there waiting for me to choose the first boot entry. This means I have to go there and plug in a monitor and keyboard.

But I can't do that remotely. How can I force it to continue booting to boot entry 1 (default) regardless of power loss or whatever?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090266/grub-alternating-between-configurations and https://askubuntu.com/questions/967816/after-enabling-hibernate-grub-menu-appears-on-start-up-with-30s-timeout

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to this one can be found in the grub file  `/etc/grub.d/00_header`

```
make_timeout ()
{
    cat << EOF
if [ "\${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=${2}
fi
EOF
}
```

Setting the timeout value to -1 will stop the count down.  Change the value to a value > 0 i.e. `set timeout=10`

this section of the file would look like

```
make_timeout ()
{
    cat << EOF
if [ "\${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=10
else
  set timeout=${2}
fi
EOF
}
```

Then run

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Comment: If I run sudo shutdown now -r, but I ping the system and notice it  hasn't come back online, when I manually turn it off and on again, is there any place to check why it crashed out?

Comment: has it got stuck at the grub again? or has it just shutdown?  Do a man "shutdown" there are a couple of files where stuff is written to.

Comment: Sometimes right after grub I'll get a black screen, then nothing. Takes a reset to get it working. Sometimes on sudo reboot or "sudo shutdown -r now" it will not reboot, just hang before even rebooting. I've just done an fschk and repaired broken packages which actually made it download a new kernal. Will see if this helps...

Comment: the change to the grub will not cause or exacerbate what you are seeing.  Doing a fsck is a good idea anyway after a power-cut.  Broken packages reads as if you have been doing some failed installs, or an install was in-progress when you rebooted/had a power-cut.  If necessary - create another question.  However, sounds like you've already got a handle on this.

Comment: I *think* this solution isn't permanent because it will be overwritten if grub packages receive updates.  The "other solution" to use "GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT" is more appropriate.  So, I have respectfully downvoted this solution and upvoted the other.

Answer (score 41):

As of Ubuntu 12.04, a more straightforward, but nevertheless undocumented, solution is to use `/etc/default/grub` to override the *recordfail* timeout:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT
```

Then run `sudo update-grub` to apply the changes.

---

The fact that such option is completely undocumented is just too bad.

Actually, the support for `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT` was added in the middle of the 12.04 cycle, starting from version `1.99-21ubuntu3.3`:

```
  grub2 (1.99-21ubuntu3.3) precise-proposed; urgency=low

[ Ben Howard ]
* Parameterization of recordfail setting. This allows users to define the
  default time out of GRUB when recordfail has been set. The curren
  setting causes hangs on headless and appliances where access to the
  console is limited or prohibited.  (LP: #669481)  [1]

-- Louis Bouchard <louis.bouchard@canonical.com>  Tue, 21 Aug 2012 10:51:58 +0200
```

More detailed information [from LaunchPad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/669481).

Comment: This works but still got white on black kernel spam after 2nd reboot, after hibernation.