# Cannot get grub menu to timeout (or go away)

Tags: grub2

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

I cannot for the life of me get the grub menu (with options) to go away.

I would like it to auto-boot into the first option. I've edited */etc/default/grub* so that it looks like the following:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

After this, I ran **sudo update-grub**. Then I realized that I had grub 2, so I ran **sudo update-grub2** (both make it look like they create the *grub.cfg* file successfully.

I restart my computer and it goes back to the grub menu and just sits there until I make a choice. This is not desirable if the power goes out... :-)

I also tried reinstalling grub using **sudo grub-install /dev/sda** - also unsuccessful

Comment: Do you by any chance have another partition that you installed Ubuntu to after setting up the current partition that you now wish to boot into automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I'm kind of new to linux. I did install over a previous Ubuntu installation, but I did not upgrade. Clean install. I may have mucked something up partition-wise... that's possible, any ideas on fixing it?

Comment: `sudo update-grub` and `sudo update-grub2` runs the same command. So, don't worry about that part.

Comment: Please you post the output of `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg
` via pastebin and share the link here. This is to see the actual `grub.cfg` generated.

Comment: Here's the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/xxe2rLhg of grub.cfg. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I force Ubuntu to boot on a stuck boot menu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55551/how-can-i-force-ubuntu-to-boot-on-a-stuck-boot-menu)

Answer (score 29):

As other answers point out, you may be a victim of the *recordfail* situation.  Editing `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` manually should be out of the question as is automatically generated.  Another suggestion seen around is to edit the `/etc/grub.d/00_header` but then it could prompt for user intervention on updates.

The easiest solution is to define the **undocumented** `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT` variable in `/etc/default/grub`.  For example:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT
```

### Edit

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55551/how-can-i-force-ubuntu-to-boot-on-a-stuck-boot-menu/244752#244752) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: After making the change, also run `update-grub` to generate the updated `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file

Comment: Don't kill the functionality of `recordfail`! You want a longer timeout if there was a failure booting. To manually clear, all you need is @sniffski's answer: `grub-editenv create`. However, there might be some other reason `recordfail` is getting set...

Comment: @CameronTacklind Do you happen to have any source for that? @sniffski's answer didn't work for me probably because of `$grub_platform = efi` as mentioned [here](https://www.tomica.net/blog/2019/02/remove-efi-grub-timeout). So setting the `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT` is a workaround in my case. That said I'd still want to avoid using the variable in an unintended way.

Comment: @Carolus Imho, you should track down the reason the fail flag is getting set instead of just patching over it.

Comment: @CameronTacklind I made a [separate question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1198898/307091) about this.

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
grub-editenv create
```

This will clear grub environment file and should boot clearly the next time.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing. This worked via SSH which made my day for a stuck on grub headless server.

Comment: `grub-editenv - unset recordfail` works as well and doesn't affect other envs that might be set

Answer (score 2):

change the `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` to zero

This is my Configuration file:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-30-generic-pae"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=10
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

First, write the name of the OS that you want to boot to directly. Mine is Ubuntu. So you will write it as in the `GRUB_DEFAULT="Ubuntu, with Linux x.x.x-xx-generic-pae"`

then I used 1 second in the `GRUB_TIMEOUT=` to give me 1 second before selecting the default OS (if I need to boot to another OS for example Xubuntu)

as for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` if you remove `quite splash` it will show you texts instead of the Ubuntu logo during the booting process (I like it this way :P )

---

There is another solution:

There is a program called [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) which helps in configuring with a GUI.

[image]

[image]

as you can see from the image. there is a box called `Unhide boot menu`. Just uncheck the box and press appy. You can access this by clicking on the advanced options arrow.

to install boot repair

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

and then run `boot-reapir` either from the terminal or from the dash.

---

3rd solution:

ou can use an easy to use GUI app called grub-customizer to make your life a little easy. As the name suggests, you can do much more than just reordering Grub menu entries with it.

You can install it by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

[image]

as you can see from the menu there is `show menu` option. Unhceck and see if it works

Comment: No change. :-/ I thought GRUB_DEFAULT was supposed to be a numeric # according to the list in the menu? Changing GRUB_TIMEOUT to 0 didn't help.

Comment: @Eric you can use 2 ways: if you know the place of your OS in the grub list you can use a number. But for me I have 4 Linux distros and 1 Windows plus the memTest and the recovery. So its hard for me to memorize their places :) just to make sure(I know you may have done it but just to make sure :P ). Did you run the `grub-update` after changing the values ?

Comment: I did run grub-update after changing the values. :-/

Comment: I installed and used the boot-repair app you provided, it works on the *first* reboot. After that, the GRUB menu is back and it sits there until I press a key. Thank you for all your help, I really appreciate it. Not sure where to go from here...

Comment: @Eric ok I found a 3rd solution check it

Answer (score 2):

`GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET` options are deprecated. So comment those out.

To skip the menu and show it only when holding <kbd>ESC</kbd>, add:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE='countdown'
GRUB_TIMEOUT=1
```

**Sample `/etc/default/grub`**

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

**`GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE`**:
If this option is set to `countdown` or `hidden`, then, **before**
displaying the menu, GRUB will wait for the the timeout set by
`GRUB_TIMEOUT` to expire.  If <kbd>ESC</kbd> is pressed during that time, it will display the GRUB menu and wait for input.

Comment: it _should_, but all it does is shows the standard menu for 1 second. At least on a brand new 16.04

Answer (score 1):

I could solve that issue by adding the following line to `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

...and then running `sudo update-grub`.

**Explanation:** The file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is generated by running `update-grub` using the files in `/etc/grub.d` and `/etc/default/grub`. Therefore you should not edit `grub.cfg`, but it can be helpful to find out why the timeout is set. Search for lines starting with `set timeout=` and then search for the next line starting with  `### END /etc/grub.d/ ...`. This might give you hints which script sets the timeout. In my case the os-prober script was responsible for the timeout. It turns out that there is a 10s hardcoded timeout in `/etc/grup.d/30_os-prober` which is not set by `GRUB_TIMEOUT`. You can either disable os-prober by `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` or edit `/etc/grup.d/30_os-prober` or use `GRUB_OS_PROBER_SKIP_LIST` to skip some of your harddisk partitions (30_os-prober is used when another OS is found somewhere). See [this Q&A for details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453038/update-grub-ignoring-some-options-in-etc-default-grub). As others pointed out another reason might be the *recordfail*, in this case set `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT`.

Answer (score 1):

My Ubuntu had always a timeout of 30 seconds either I would have set a value or not. Here after is how I have found out that *recordfail was the missing value*.

**1. Verify the actual grub script `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`**

IMHO, the best way to verify what Grub will do, is to open `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. It is the script automatically generated by `grub-mkconfig` using templates from `/etc/grub.d` and settings from `/etc/default/grub`.

Around the line 109, you will see see something like:

```
108 if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
109   set timeout=30 # Note here this value
110 else
111   if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
112     set timeout_style=hidden
113     set timeout=3
114   # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
115   # unavailable.
116   elif sleep --interruptible 3 ; then
117     set timeout=0
118   fi
119 fi
```

In my case with the help of that generated script, I could find out that the `recordfail` variable was unset.

**2. If the `recordfail` variable is unset, set it**

Open `/etc/default/grub` in your favourite text editor (e.g. vim) and then set the variable `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT` to a given value, for example 5 seconds.

Your config file should look like:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=5
```

**3. Update the configuration to run with `update-grub`**

Last step, update the configuration to run with `update-grub`. For now on, GRUB2 will use the set timeout. This command will regenerate the `/boot/grub.cfg` file.

**4. Verify the generated script result**

Again, open `/boot/grub.cfg` and check the result around the line 109:

```
108 if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
109   set timeout=5 # Note here this value
110 else
111   if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
112     set timeout_style=hidden
113     set timeout=3
114   # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
115   # unavailable.
116   elif sleep --interruptible 3 ; then
117     set timeout=0
118   fi
119 fi
```

Note that the value at line 109 is now 5 instead of 30 as before.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that the grub menu appeared always after I used the AUFS (unionfs) to put the root filesystem readonly. I had phisically to hit the enter key at the server after every boot. I followed the instructions here : [disable grub 2 menu](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/how-to-disable-grub-2-menu-even-after-server-crash-796562/). Since, I had no problems at all.

Edit the /boot/grub/grub.cfg and change:

```
if [ ${recordfail} = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
```

To

```
if [ ${recordfail} = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
```

Comment: The before and after in your solution are exactly the same.

Comment: `set timeout=-1` is not the same as `set timeout=1`.


The former is "wait forever", and the latter is "wait for one second".