# GRUB menu shows on every boot despite /etc/default/grub settings

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2

For some reason I cannot stop the GRUB menu from appearing every boot on my Ubuntu 14.04.05 installation.

I have ensured that my /etc/default/grub file has GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 and GRUB_TIMEOUT=0 and I then ran sudo update-grub, to no avail.

The version on the GRUB menu says GNU GRUB version v2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.14 if that helps at all, and if there's anything else that may be helpful just ask and I'll respond with it.

I searched around and couldn't find much on this topic.

Edit since OP wasn't clear enough:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Those are the pertinent settings currently in my /etc/default/grub, and I run sudo update-grub, which completes successfully it seems.

However, the GRUB menu still appears at boot.

Final edit for posterity:

None of the traditional solutions worked, I tried regenerating the grub file after ensuring that /etc/default/grub contained the proper information, to no avail.

What finally worked for me is entering the command:

```
grub-editenv create
```

as documented in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/339218/754899) answer.

Comment: To elaborate the answer: grub on start reads `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. The content of that file is autogenerated from `/etc/default/grub`, so what you were missing is forcing regeneration of the file.

Answer (score 3):

Open `/etc/default/grub` with your favorite text editor.
Make sure the following lines are not commented out or add them if they don't exist.

```
...
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
...
```

Finally run :

```
sudo update-grub
```