# Grub does not autoboot the default option after upgrade to 12.10

Tags: upgrade, grub2, 12.10

I recently upgraded Ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10 and since that time, the system does not automatically boot. It always opens the boot menu, and I have to press Enter to make it boot Ubuntu.

It seems to be ignoring the timeout value, and using a 'neverending' timeout.

There are no other systems (no dual boot), only the options originally installed by default Ubuntu 12.04 installation.

My `/etc/default/grub` has only these effective options:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT='Ubuntu'
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

I experimented with `GRUB_DEFAULT`, giving it values '0', '1', 'Ubuntu' but nothing helps.

Yes I always run `update-grub` afterwards.

How can I make the system booting again ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I force Ubuntu to boot on a stuck boot menu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55551/how-can-i-force-ubuntu-to-boot-on-a-stuck-boot-menu)

Answer (score 11):

Add the following to `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
```

Save and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the following set of values in my `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=5
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

I have several other operating systems on 
my computer and the GRUB_DEFAULT setting 
seems to set the specific initial highlighted 
item on the list starting at 0 and counting 
upward.  During the countdown time of 10 
seconds I can change between the other entries 
on the list.

I would suggest you try the following settings making sure that you comment the `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` parameter:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

Then work backwards from that, gradually making the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` or `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` parameters 1 or 2 to shorten the wait on the default selected system.

Remember that you may need to Ctrl+Alt+T to 
get to the terminal for sudo gedit of the 
file.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at /etc/grub.d/00_header You would see these lines:

```
make_timeout ()
{
    cat << EOF
if [ "\${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=${GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT:--1}
else
  set timeout=${2}
fi
EOF
}
```

basically, grub2 is capable of detecting errors in boot process and fallback to manual booting.

Changing these lines to something like

```
make_timeout ()
{
    cat << EOF
  set timeout=${2}
EOF
}
```

and regenerating grub config with `sudo update-grub` should fix the problem.
The interesting question, though is why grub keep thinking booting fails after you manually press Enter.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. I didn't have to use the live disk cause I could manually boot the os by selecting the option in grub and pressing enter. This fixed my problem. Good luck!

http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.