# How to auto boot to ubuntu instead of showing text mode grub menu on power failure

Tags: grub2

Text mode boot screen shows when the PC is started.
(it shows when for some reason, restart was not done safely, but in remote location I must need to boot the PC on power on)

[image]

How can I on power ignore this screen and take the default to boot urgent to Ubuntu?

Comment: See a real answer for this here  http://askubuntu.com/a/244752/45849

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To disable the Grub boot menu from showing at boot, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the Grub timeout

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

Save and reboot.

Comment: Mitch: could you review edits and roll back to V3 if needed (not my call as I don't have the experience)
@Community: just to inform you...

Comment: @Mitch - I am using Ubuntu 14.04. GRUB_TIMEOUT is already set to 0 in /etc/default/grub. Still the grub menu appears at boot. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Guanidene did you use sudo update-grub and restart after the change?. Also take a look at GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0 see this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/214972/grub-does-not-autoboot-the-default-option-after-upgrade-to-12-10

Comment: you should run `sudo update-grub` after changing the file.