# How to make sure, that grub always starts the default entry after a timeout?

Tags: boot, grub2

When booting the Ubuntu system went wrong and the user is forced to cut off power, there is a feature, that disables automatic selection of grub menu upon next boot.

Normally this is a nice feature to have, but sometimes it gets triggered when I power on the system remotely via WOL.

Is there any way to disable it?

Comment: Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/a/244752/158442

Comment: @muru Yes, it is a duplicate. Should I delete the question, or leave it so the others can reach the answer under different search phrase?

Comment: I'd suggest keeping it. The moderators can close it as a duplicate.