# Fix/Prevent GRUB from waiting with a different timeout on resuming from hibernate

Tags: boot, grub2, hibernate, timeout

When resuming from hibernate state, my computer waits at the GRUB screen for 30 seconds, which is different from the custom timeout that I have set by editing the grub configuration file.

**The custom timeout works properly for normal boot from complete shutdown but waits as stated above while resuming from hibernate state.**

How can I set same timeout for resuming from hibernate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After enabling hibernate grub menu appears on start-up with 30s timeout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967816/after-enabling-hibernate-grub-menu-appears-on-start-up-with-30s-timeout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by adding the following line to the Grub configuration file:

```
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=N
```

*Put `N=timeout` that you want when resuming from hibernate*

Answer Source: https://serverfault.com/a/598805/439371 and https://askubuntu.com/a/251920

**Complete steps:**

- `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
- Add this line at the end of the file, save the file and close gedit (*Set N to the desired timeout*):

  `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=N`.
- `sudo update-grub`

Comment: This is not the correct fix see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1233077/8570