# I have set Grub timeout is 4 sec. But sometimes, grub start to boot after 30 secs. Why? What's wrong?

Tags: grub2, 19.04

gedit /etc/default/grub output is:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=4
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

**Let me know if u need more output.** This happens like 1 out of 5 times. But I do not want this to happen anymore. *Any help would be appreciated.*

Comment: It is just using the default timeout value. See `grep timeout /boot/grub/grub.cfg` output. It happened to me also once. But, I do not remember the case.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli u are right. I am seeing an output, "... set timeout=30 ...." What should I do now? Decrease it to 4 sec? Is this a normal thing? Because usually people only recommend editing "etc/default/grub", so..?!

Comment: You might also look at [https://askubuntu.com/a/244752/283721](https://askubuntu.com/a/244752/283721)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens on hard reset or forced reboot.

The value of 30 seconds is set in `/etc/grub.d/00_header`

```
  set timeout=${GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT:-30}
```

If you want to change it, you have to specify your own value in `/etc/default/grub`

```
sudo editor /etc/default/grub
```

Add new line:

```
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=4
```

and update grub:

```
update-grub2
```

Comment: thanks. I hope this works. Is there a way to confirm this?

Comment: possibly by holding power button down until PC goes off, but I don't recommend it, since this can mess your hard drive or filesystem