# update-grub not working -- No medium found

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, lvm

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with LVM and UEFI on a Thinkpad T480.

Whenever I run `sudo update-grub`, I get this output:

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-29-generic
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-28-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-21-generic
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
```

My changes do not appear to take effect after running the command.

I don't have a volume called /dev/sdb...I don't understand why it would look for that.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1834250

Comment: @mook765 I tried out your link, and it stopped the errors, but my changes to grub still do not appear to take effect.

Comment: I realized that the error that `update-grub` gave me and the issue with my changes not taking effect were unrelated. I fixed this issue by following [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55551/how-can-i-force-ubuntu-to-boot-on-a-stuck-boot-menu/244752#244752): I added the line `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT` to my grub configuration.

Answer (score 12):

Solution from [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1834250/comments/11) on launchpad [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1834250/):

Add a `global_filter = [ "r|/dev/sda|", "r|/dev/sdb|" ]` to the file `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` :

```
 143         # Example
 144         # Accept every block device:
 145         # filter = [ "a|.*|" ]
 146         # Reject the cdrom drive:
 147         # filter = [ "r|/dev/cdrom|" ]
 148         # Work with just loopback devices, e.g. for testing:
 149         # filter = [ "a|loop|", "r|.*|" ]
 150         # Accept all loop devices and ide drives except hdc:
 151         # filter = [ "a|loop|", "r|/dev/hdc|", "a|/dev/ide|", "r|.*|" ]
 152         # Use anchors to be very specific:
 153         # filter = [ "a|^/dev/hda8$|", "r|.*|" ]
 154         # 
 155         # This configuration option has an automatic default value.
 156         # filter = [ "a|.*|" ]
 157         global_filter = [ "r|/dev/sda|", "r|/dev/sdb|" ]
```

When you ran `sudo update-grub` before applying that modification, you had this error:

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
GRUB-Konfigurationsdatei wird erstellt …
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  .
  .
  .
Linux-Abbild gefunden: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-52-generic
initrd-Abbild gefunden: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-52-generic
Linux-Abbild gefunden: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-generic
initrd-Abbild gefunden: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-48-generic
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  .
  .
  .
Startmenüeintrag für UEFI-Firmware-Einstellungen wird hinzugefügt erledigt
```

After you apply the modification and you run again `sudo update-grub`, the error should be gone:

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
GRUB-Konfigurationsdatei wird erstellt …
Linux-Abbild gefunden: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-52-generic
initrd-Abbild gefunden: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-52-generic
Linux-Abbild gefunden: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-generic
initrd-Abbild gefunden: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-48-generic
Startmenüeintrag für UEFI-Firmware-Einstellungen wird hinzugefügt erledigt
```

Comment: Instead of `global_filter = [ "r|/dev/sda|", "r|/dev/sdb|" ]` you could use `[ "r|/dev/sd[a-b]|" ]`